# Possible non geometric intuition for the mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, intuition

Is it possible to "see" the mean value theorem when one is only thinking of numerical values without visualizing a graph? Perhaps through a real world problem?

Comment: how does that make you think of a rate of change equals to the average slope of the path?

Comment: "I drove exactly $60$ miles in an hour.  At some point I must have been going at exactly $60$ mph."  After all, if I never hit $60$ then I was either slower than $60$ or faster than $60$ the whole way, and in either case I couldn't have gone exactly $60$ miles.

Comment: @lulu: Or you were driving slower than 60 mph in the first half hour and faster than 60 mph in the second half hour :) Only if we assume that your pattern of movement was differentiable, we can derive your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you @lulu :)

Comment: @Luyw There's isn't much new, but you may find the question & answers at MSE's [Mean Value Theorem Motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568121/mean-value-theorem-motivation) somewhat interesting.